# React.js genera canvas en el html boilerplate de Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, chrome

Antes de nada hola a todos.

Estoy desarrollando una app web con el stack MERN. Llevo un par de días que me he dado cuenta que al hacer click en algún link interno de la web, en la pestaña "Elementos" del navegador Chrome, me aparece un canvas justo después de la etiqueta de apertura de HTML.

Por supuesto no tengo ninguna referencia a Canvas en mi código. He estado investigando por si hubiera algún bug pero no hay nada.

Añadir que con Firefox no me pasa. Solo con Chrome.

Alguien tiene idea de algún posible motivo?

Adjunto imágenes.

[image: Previa antes del "error"]

[image: Aparicion canvas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi igual me sucedió los mismo. Buscando ayuda no encontré absolutamente nada. Lo que hice y funciono, fue restaurar Chrome por defecto, haciendo eso, ya se elimino ese canvas que aparece arriba del head.

Configuración >> Configuración Avanzada >> Recuperar Ajustes y Borrar >> Restaura los valores predeterminados originales de la configuración .

Suerte!